# Providing a basic filesystem from a char driver

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver

I have an existing Linux device driver that exposes a basic char device to userland.  (I am not its original author, but I'm trying to modify it.)

Currently it provides a maze of ioctl functions to do various things (though also wrapped in a handy library so most user code doesn't need to deal with the details of it).

One of the things that it does is to provide a sub-stream interface, where given a bunch of device-specific identifying information (including a string and some numeric ids) it can read or write (but not both at once) some data (up to a small number of MB) in a strictly sequential manner.  Currently it does this with explicit ioctls.

I'm wondering if there is a way to leverage the existing `file_operations` infrastructure or similar to provide either a virtual filesystem or just an `ioctl` that can return a new already-open fd that can then be used with `read`/`write`/`close` (but not `lseek`) from userland as you'd normally expect?

The device does have a concept of a filename (that's the string) but it is not possible to enumerate existing valid filenames (only to try to open a specific filename and see if it gives an error or not), and the filename is not sufficient to open a stream by itself, which is why I'm currently leaning more towards the "special open" ioctl on the parent device rather than trying to expose things directly in some userland-visible fs that can be `open`ed directly.  (Also there's no concept of subdirs and only basic write-protect permissions, so a full fs seems like overkill anyway.)  But I'm willing to be persuaded otherwise if there's a better way to do it.

I have written basic char drivers from scratch myself before, so I'm reasonably confident that I can get the read/write ops and other supporting things to work; I'm just not sure how to best handle that initial step of opening the handle.

I'm currently targeting kernel 3.2+.

---

**Edit**: The main reason that I think making an actual filesystem (or trying to expose it via procfs or sysfs) wouldn't work is that there's no way to populate a directory -- the only ops available are "open for read" and "open for write", and there's no way to tell which names are valid prior to the open attempt (the files are stored in external hardware and accessed via a protocol I cannot change).  If I'm missing something and it is possible to support this sort of thing, that would be useful to know as well.

Comment: Some thoughts:You can implement your files similar to /proc files.Provide read/write operations by your driver.If you don't want your files exposed to the file system, then you should not attach your the files in the file system tree.But, open() system call needs a "path" in a filesystem to start with, so I would say, you definitely need a special open(may be ioctl) to find your file struct of the file you want to read/write, and associate it with a process fd.

Comment: Ok, but that's just restating what I'm trying to do.  It doesn't give me any hints for how to actually create an open fd that can be passed back to userspace from an ioctl, which is what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly create a file system where readdir() is not implemented, but the open() method is.   It's normally not done because it's not particularly user-friendly, but it certainly is doable.

You're targetting really ancient kernels if you're looking at 3.2 -- the upstream kernel developers aren't even bother to *try* to backport security fixes that far back, so I certainly wouldn't recommend shipping something as ancient as 3.2, but it's technically doable.

All you need to do is to implement lookup() method in the inode_operations structure for directories.  You'll need to figure out some way of creating inodes with unique inode numbers, that contains private information so you can identify the subtream.   The inode will have a file_operations structure that implements the read/write methods for reading and writing the substream.

You can try looking at a simple file system such as cramfs or minix to see how things are done.

Comment: So every call to `lookup()` succeeds with some unique dentry containing a unique inode?  And that won't annoy caches, or anything else?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using a modern kernel, since it would take me more time to do the research on a prehistoric, ancient, no-longer-supported-by-upstream, security-bug-ridden, 3.2 kernel.   :-)   But on a modern kernel, the lookup parameter takes a struct inode *dir for the directory where you are doing a lookup, and a struct dentry *dentry which contains the filename in dentry->d_name.   The file system will then allocate an inode structure (using some variant of iget), fill it in with with the appropriate information for the inode being opened, and then...

Comment: ... and then call d_splice_entry() to splice the inode information into now-instanciated struct dentry *dentry.   The VFS layer will take care of caching the dentry layer, and if you return some kind of error, via ERR_PTR(-NOENT), the VFS will cache that response and not bother calling lookup() the second time.   So if you care about a name being invalid at time t, and valid at time t+x, you may need to provide a d_revalidate() function which always returns false to force the VFS layer to always call your lookup function().

Comment: (Again, your mileage may vary if you are using an ancient 3.2 kernel, but for the love of all that's holy, you *really* don't want to be doing that.   If someone gets killed, or personal identifying information gets disclosed due to bugs in an ancient unsupported kernel, do you really want that on your conscience, even if the "if this kills a million people, this software is under no warranties other than a return of the pro-rated purchase price" disclaimer gets you off the legal liability hook?)

Comment: In any case, no, the kernel does not use readdir() to populate any of its caches.   It uses lookup() to cache the results of a directory lookup operation, and it's important to note that it caches both positive lookups (those that result in binding an inode to a directory plus filename lookup request), and those that are negative (those that result in "file not found", for example).  This is because most file systems have an on-disk representation where this doesn't change out from under the kernel.  But for network file system or a synthetic file system, that's what d_revalidate() is for.

Comment: FWIW, 3.2 is in fact still supported by upstream -- it was updated just last month.  And it was the standard kernel in the previous generation of Debian (wheezy, now "oldstable"), so it's only slightly ancient.  But that's beside the point.  Thanks for the suggestion; it'll probably take me a while to properly grok the filesystem APIs and how they interact in order to try this out.  Is there any documentation other than by example (the `Documentation/fs` tree seems out of date)?

Comment: Ben Hutchins (from Debian) is the 3.2 maintainer --- it's not one of the kernel trees supported by Greg K-H.    What tends to happen with the stable trees is that people will try taking the kernel patches from upstream and just try seeing if they apply.  If they do, great.  If they don't, they get dropped.  By the time you get to 3.2, most of the security patches don't apply, and the upstream kernel developers don't provide any support.   I will test the Greg K-H's stable kernels to make sure the blindly/mechanically applied patches don't cause regressions.  I don't do that with 3.2.